# ServerAlias or Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have a site running at

```
www.domainA.com
```

and need this to be pointed to

```
www.domainB.com/domainA
```

`www.domainB.com` is running WordPress on Apache and we currently have a `ServerName` for domainB and a `ServerAlias` set up for domainA.

Am I right in thinking that this alias would take precedence over any 301 redirects we have set up in a `.htaccess` file on domainB.

At the moment the `www.domainA.com` is just redirecting to `www.domainB.com`.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "pointed to"? htaccess files are only read when a URI path is mapped to the file system. So an Alias in your virtual host (or global host) will take precedence. The correct way is to stop using htaccess files (unless you have no choice). Since you cannot use Alias in the htaccess file you should move the redirect to the virtual host.

Comment: www.domainA.com should resolve to www.domainB.com/domainA where www.domainB.com/domainA is a wordpress page not an actual folder.

i.e. when I browse to www.domainA.com I end up at www.domainB.com/domainA

Comment: A redirect in you virtual host is probably best then.

Comment: "any 301 redirects we have set up in a .htaccess file on domainB." - Any redirects from domainA to domainB would be set up in a .htaccess file on domainA, not domainB. (But I guess you must already be doing that?)

Comment: Why are you using a htaccess file - put it in the main server config.

Answer (score 0):

Like other users are saying I think configuring virtual hosts would be the best way. There is a great guide on how to do that [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

While following that guide simply add this to your domainA.conf file

```
<Location /domainB>
     ProxyPass http://localhost:domainBport
     ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:domainBport
</Location>
```

This assumes both domains are running on the same apache server.